# Which theta function is $\theta(x;q) = (x;q)(q/x;q)$?

Tags: analytic-number-theory, theta-functions

The physics paper I am reading very non-chalantly defines the theta function as

$$ \theta(x;q) = (x;q)(q/x;q) \hspace{0.5in}  \tilde{\theta}(x;q) = x^{-1/2}(x;q)(q/x;q)  $$

where they are using the [$q$-Pochammer symbol](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-Pochhammer_symbol).  This notation is a bit compressed it reads:
$$ \theta(x;q) = \prod_{i=0}^\infty( 1 - xq^i) \prod_{i=0}^\infty( 1 - (q/x)q^i)$$

There are different versions of the Jacobi [Triple Product Identity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_triple_product) floating around.  For example:

$$  \prod_{n > 0} (1 + q^{n-\frac{1}{2}}z)(1 + q^{n-\frac{1}{2}}z^{-1}) 
= \left( \sum_{l \in \mathbb{Z}} q^{\frac{l^2}{2} }z^l \right) \prod_{n > 0} \frac{1}{1-q^n}$$

However this doesn't seem to match up with the combination of q-Pochhammer symbols listed above.

How to expand $\theta(x;q)$ as an infinite series and recognize the infinite product?  Wolfram Alpha was [inconclusive](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Series%5BQPochhammer%5Bx%2C+q%5D+QPochhammer%5Bq%2Fx%2C+q%5D%2C+%7Bq%2C0%2C10%7D%5D).

Comment: Setting  $x=-q^{1/2}z$ gets you further, but the Euler factor $(q; q)$ is then still missing; and the original theta functions tend to use $q$ (and $z$) squared. If only ratios of theta functions with the same $q$ are of interest, this shortcut works, but it overloads the notion of *theta function* even further. By the way, here are [some helpful formulae](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ramanujan_theta_function).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ever since Jacobi introduced theta functions there have been a number of notations, variations and generalizations of them. Even Jacobi used more than one notation for theta functions. Read the Wikipedia article [Jacobi theta functions (notational variations)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jacobi_theta_functions_(notational_variations)). The variations include choices of the two variables and constant terms or factors. You would only be confused to learn about all that.

A fairly standard form of one theta function is: $\theta_4(u,q):=\sum_{n=-\infty}^\infty (-1)^n \cos(2nu)\;q^{n^2},$ but also $\theta_4(u,q^{1/2})=(q;q)(x;q)(q/x;q)\;$ where $\;x=q^{1/2}e^{2iu}.$ Thus $\;\theta_4(u,q^{1/2})/(q;q)=(x;q)(q/x;q).\;$ I am not sure where the $x^{-1/2}$ comes from in $\tilde{\theta}(x;q)$.

Comment: i'm trying to take this variety of theta functions as a feature rather than a defect... however what happens when I am reading a paper and they choose one theta function over the other?

Comment: @cactus314 Please read the last paragraph of the Wikipedia article..